# Sending a method as a parameter via reflection for registering a callback

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

Is there a way for me to call a method via reflection with a parameter being another method?

```
private void CalendarPopup_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var parent = GetParent(CalendarPopup, typeof(Popup));
    if (parent != null)
    {
        object parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(CalendarPopup);
        Type parentWindowType = parentWindow.GetType();

        var methodInfo = parentWindowType.GetMethod("RegisterMouseDownCallback");
        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
            object[] parameters = new object[1];
            //************************
            parameters[0] = PopupCallback; //Problem here
            //************************
            methodInfo.Invoke(parentWindow, parameters);
        }
    }
}

private void PopupCallback(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
    var obj = args.Source;
    if (obj != null)
    {
        var parent = GetParent(obj as DependencyObject, typeof(Popup));
        if (parent != null && !parent.Equals(CalendarPopup))
        {
            this.CalendarPopup.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code belongs to a UserControl which is actually loaded via reflection, so, neither the UserControl or Window which houses RegisterMouseDownCallback know much about each other.

This is the code for the RegisterMouseDownCallback in the window:

```
   private IList<MetroWindowMouseDownCallback> callbacks = new List<MainWindowMouseDownCallback>();

    public delegate void MetroWindowMouseDownCallback(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args); 

    public MetroWindow() : base()
    {
        PreviewMouseUp += MetroWindow_MouseUp;
    }

    public void RegisterMouseDownCallback(MetroWindowMouseDownCallback callback)
    {
        callbacks.Add(callback);
    }

    public void UnRegisterMouseDownCallback(MetroWindowMouseDownCallback callback)
    {
        if (callbacks.Contains(callback))
            callbacks.Remove(callback);
    }

    void MetroWindow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var callback in callbacks)
            callback.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, naturally this is possible. If you can accomplish it without reflection, you can accomplish it with reflection (albeit at a cost in performance).

In your case, the issue is that you are probably used to simply using a method group name (e.g. "PopupCallback") where a delegate instance is required. In the usual situation, the compiler can tell from the context that a delegate instance is required (e.g. `PreviewMouseUp += MetroWindow_MouseUp`), and so the compiler automatically adds code to create a new delegate instance using that method group name.

In your case, you are trying to assign a method group name to a variable (or in this case, an array element) that simply has the type `object`. This isn't enough information for the compiler to figure out what you mean, so you need to give it a little help by specifying the delegate type you want.

For example:

```
parameters[0] = (MetroWindowMouseDownCallback)PopupCallback;
```

By casting the method group name to the appropriate delegate type, this informs the compiler what your intent is, and it will add the necessary code to create the delegate instance you want passed to the method.

Comment: So I would also move the `public delegate void MetroWindowMouseDownCallback(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)` to a library shared by both?

Comment: @Hank: if you want to be able to do it exactly as you've shown, yes. The caller of `RegisterMouseDownCallback()` needs to know and use the type of that method's parameter when calling it, even if via reflection. Of course, if you are willing to change the signature, or to add an overload that takes a more general-purpose delegate type (e.g. `Action<object, MouseButtonEventArgs>` or `EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs>`)  and wraps it in the correct one for the original method, that would work also.